# Format data to just return a time in the format hh:mm using date-fns

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I am searching for a function that takes in a datetime like this: "2020-06-29T07:30:00+02:00" and just returns the time from the date in the format hh:mm. I am using date-fns, but unfortunately I am unable to find such a function there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://date-fns.org/v2.14.0/docs/format

```
import {format} from 'date-fns';

format(new Date('2020-06-29T07:30:00+02:00'), 'HH:mm')
```

or

```
format(new Date('2020-06-29T07:30:00+02:00'), 'p')
```